# How to add foreign key to an existing column in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I am trying to add foreign key to my existing column using below query

```
ALTER TABLE Sub_Category_Master 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Category_ID) REFERENCES Category_Master(Category_ID)
```

but I'm getting an error

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Sub_Categ__Categ__5812160E". The conflict occurred in database "shaadikarbefikar_new", table "shaadikarbefikar.Category_Master", column 'Category_ID'.

Comment: Does every categoryid is in sub... exist in the target table?

Comment: @marc_s It's not working yet. still getting error.
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_SubCategoryMaster_CategoryMaster". The conflict occurred in database "shaadikarbefikar_new", table "shaadikarbefikar.Category_Master", column 'Category_ID'.

Answer (score 6):

Well, the error clearly tells you that `Category_ID` in your `Sub_Category_Master` table contains some values that are **not present** in `Category_Master` (column `Category_ID`). But that's exactly the point of having a foreign key constraint - making sure your child table (`Sub_Category_Master`) only uses *defined* values from its parent table.

Therefore, you must fix those "voodoo" values first, before you're able to establish this foreign key relationship. I would also **strongly recommend** to **explicitly name** that constraint yourself, to avoid those system-generated, but not really very useful constraint names like `FK__Sub_Categ__Categ__5812160E`:

```
ALTER TABLE Sub_Category_Master 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SubCategoryMaster_CategoryMaster
    FOREIGN KEY (Category_ID) REFERENCES Category_Master(Category_ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE Sub_Category_Master
ADD CONSTRAINT FKSub_Category_Master_Category_ID FOREIGN KEY (Category_ID)
    REFERENCES  Category_Master(Category_ID);
```

Answer (score -4):

```
CREATE TABLE Orders 
(
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),

    CONSTRAINT FK_PersonOrder 
        FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
);
```